# How to display % on stacked column chart SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

My data looks like this:

[image]

```
Column PremiumVsPlan = Premium / TotalForcast
```

How can I display `PremiumVsPlan` columns on a top of my `RunningTotal` stacked column chart, so it would make sense? Like this:

[image]

This is what I got so far in design mode:

[image]

But when I run it, than it looks not like it should. You can barely see a fraction of `PremiumVsPlan`

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Which version of SSRS?

Comment: Visual studio 2010.  Thanks

Comment: For starters, you should change the value for the orange bar to [Premium]-[TotalForecast].  Values hovering around 100 will never be more than a miniscule portion on a scale of 8,000,000.  Then you can figure out how to get the labels to populate from the Premiumvsplan field.

Comment: I'm not sure I would you a stacked column chart for this. I would create another column with a running total for Premium and either use a line chart  showing the two running total lines, or a combo chart with a columns showing the forecast and a line showing the premium. Either way you can use the data in your PremiumVsPlan column as a datalabel to show your % variance.